# RestSharp doesn't work on ASP.NET Core (HTTP POST method)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, restsharp

Login model code:

```
namespace Tools.Models
{
    public class Login
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The username field is required")]
        public string username { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The password field is required")]
        public string password { get; set; }

        public string LoginUrl { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
public ActionResult SubmitLogin(Login model)
{
    var client = new RestClient(model.LoginUrl);
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    var dataToSend = new
        {
            userName = model.UserName,
            password = model.Password,
            reCaptcha = new
            {
                recaptchaResponse = "111",
                isReCaptchaEnabled = false
            }
        };
        
    string jsonToSend = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataToSend);
    request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", jsonToSend, ParameterType.RequestBody);

    var response = client.Execute(request);

    if (response.IsSuccessful && response.Cookies.Count > 0)
    {
        var cookieName = "AuthToken";
        var authCookie = response.Cookies.FirstOrDefault(cookie => cookie.Name == cookieName);

        if (authCookie != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(authCookie.Value))
        {
            // set header
            var cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName, authCookie.Value);
            cookie.Expires = authCookie.Expires;
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
               
            return Redirect....;
        }
    }
        
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

I'm trying to run this controller method but on ASP.NET Core, it doesn't work (it doesn't work only on ASP.NET Core, generally the code is working fine).

The compiler doesn't recognize `response.AddParameter`, `HttpCookie`, `RestClient`, `RestRequest` etc.

(generally, this code login to another domain, get the authTokken and save it in the cookies)

Example for an error:

> The type or namespace name 'RestRequest' could not be found

How can I modify the code to fix the problems?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you add the NuGet package for RestSharp?

Comment: And did you add the `using RestSharp;` directive?

Comment: it is still doesnt recognize parts of the code...
for example "POST" from "Method.POST", client from "var response = client.Execute(request);", "authCookie.Value" etc.

Comment: I believe the latest version of RestSharp only has an async API. Like `PostAsync`, `GetAsync`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `AddJsonBody` for sending a pre-serialized JSON sting. It's clearly [described](https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#addjsonbody) in the documentation.

Either send an object with `AddJsonBody` or use `AddStringBody` with `DataFormat.Json`.

[image]